# Returning a value from one method to another method

Tags: java, string, arraylist, return

```
/* Assume as precondition that the list of players is not empty.
 * Returns the winning score, that is, the lowest total score.
 * @return winning score
 */
public int winningScore() {
    Player thePlayer = players.get(0);
    int result = thePlayer.totalScore();
    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++){
        int p = players.get(i).totalScore();
        if (p < result) {
            result = players.get(i).totalScore();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

/* Returns the list of winners, that is, the names of those players
 * with the lowest total score.
 * The winners' names should be stored in the same order as they occur
 * in the tournament list.
 * If there are no players, return empty list.
 * @return list of winners' names
 */
public ArrayList<String> winners() {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
        if (!players.isEmpty())
            return result;
}
```

As it states in the comments, I am trying to return the winningScore() result in the winners method so it returns the the winner/winners names.

I have managed to only return all of the winners but am a little confused if it should be calling from the winningScore() method or not?

I understand my current code is incorrect for winners

Any push/hint in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Well it looks like you should be calling `winningScore()` from the `winners()` method to start with... e.g. `int scoreToMatch = winningScore();`. Then loop over all the players and see which ones *have* that score.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to find all player objects with the winning score in your winners method.

- To do this you need to first calculate the winning score by calling
  your winningScore method.
- Next you find all player objects whose totalScore equals the
  previously calculated winning score. You want to return those.

The resulting code for your winners method would then look like this:

```
public ArrayList<String> winners() {
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

    int winningScore = winningScore();  

    for (int i = 0; i < players.size(); i++)
        if (players.get(i).totalScore() == winningScore)
            result.add(players.get(i).getName())

    return result;
}
```

If you want to simplify the code, you can substitute the `for` loop by a loop using the `ArrayList` iterator like this, since you do not use the index variable `i`:

```
for (Player player : players) {
    if (player.totalScore() == winningScore)
        result.add(player.getName())
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just to be clear, this runs a loop through the players list and compares totalScore with the winningScore method to then add the winner name(s) to the ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>() ?

Comment: To return an empty list, would you just call a return result?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Now it adds the player name (via the method getName() in the player object) to the result list. Normally I would recommend to return an ArrayList<Player> instead of a list of strings, because you can do more with the player list than only with the string list.

Comment: If the players list is empty the for loop wouldn't run, which leads to an empty result list because no player name would be added to the result list

Comment: Thanks again for the help (both the coding and explanation of the logic). Got the method working thanks to you!